# How to center path in svg without considering its size in html?

Tags: html, svg

I have a simple `svg` hamburger menu like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="25" height="25">
  <symbol id="bar">
      <title>Bar</title>
      <desc>Bar for forming hamburger menu button</desc>
      <rect width="100" height="10"></rect>
  </symbol>
  <g id="hamburger" transform="translate(0, 0)">
      <use y="0" xlink:href="#bar" />
      <use y="20" xlink:href="#bar" />
      <use y="40" xlink:href="#bar" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now if I want to center it, I can use `translate` to do the job, but I have to calculate based on the size of the svg that will be rendered in html (i.e `25px`, as shown in `width` and `height`).

Is it possible to center it without considering HTML? Is there any no-brainer equivalent in SVG to the following in CSS?

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: You do define the viewBox of your svg, you don't have to consider the rendered size, you can work safely from that viewBox.

Comment: if the `.child` is the svg element you need to add `display:block;` to the `.child`

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements do automatic centering by default anyway. So all you need to do is set the width of the SVG to be the whatever you wish.  For example, in the snippet below I've set it to be the same as its parent (`width: 100%`).

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  background: linen;
}

.parent svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="25" height="25">
    <symbol id="bar">
      <title>Bar</title>
      <desc>Bar for forming hamburger menu button</desc>
      <rect width="100" height="10"></rect>
    </symbol>
    <g id="hamburger" transform="translate(0, 0)">
      <use y="0" xlink:href="#bar" />
      <use y="20" xlink:href="#bar" />
      <use y="40" xlink:href="#bar" />
    </g>
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Flexbox. Here just placing the SVG in a parent element that is displayed as flex and then `justify-content: center`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: silver;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="25" height="25">
    <symbol id="bar">
      <title>Bar</title>
      <desc>Bar for forming hamburger menu button</desc>
      <rect width="100" height="10"></rect>
    </symbol>
    <g id="hamburger" transform="translate(0, 0)">
      <use y="0" xlink:href="#bar" />
      <use y="20" xlink:href="#bar" />
      <use y="40" xlink:href="#bar" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```